# i got an exception when i'm trying to add items to shopping cart through cart

Tags: c#

```
cartitem i = new cartitem() { iid = int.Parse(pid), iqty = int.Parse(pqty)};
```

got exception

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

trying to add items in cart using this action method `cart()`

Comment: `pid` and/or `pqty` is null.

Comment: ArgumentNullException != [NRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)... (still duplicate, just different question)

Answer (score 1):

The Exception `System.ArgumentNullException` is raised by the CLR when the parameter passed in `Parse` method is `null`.

Which in your case is either `pid` or `pqty` OR both.

Check this Microsoft document for more details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2

I would suggest, add code validating values of both the parameters before you create new object of the item and add it to cart. If any one of them is null or unacceptable value provide a helpful message to user.